# Php Multidimensional Array - Update value based on a key ID

Tags: php, arrays

I has been reading several questions and answers, but i do not find yet a solution to my issue. I am trying to update a json file generated in a CMS and stored in mysql for a counter. Is a multidimensional array, and the part i need to update is this nested section under the key=>15:

```
array (size=39)
'admin_label' => string 'C04' (length=3)
'number' => string '194' (length=3)
'number_addtext' => string '+' (length=1)
'duration' => string '2400' (length=4)
'counter_title' => string 'PAGES ACTIVE' (length=14)
```

So i just json decode it and update the values this way:

```
 $json[15]['columns'][1]['addons'][2]['settings']['number'] = $val1;
 $json[15]['columns'][2]['addons'][2]['settings']['number'] = $val2;
 $json[15]['columns'][3]['addons'][2]['settings']['number'] = $val3;
 $json[15]['columns'][4]['addons'][2]['settings']['number'] = $val4;
```

then i encode it and update the database. But if the parent key change, the script will not work.

I would like to find a way to search, by example, the value 'C04' as a reference or even the counter title 'PAGES ACTIVE' and then update the value of the key 'number' of that nested array, this way if the parent key change the script will work ok. Is this possible? Something like this:

```
 function findarray($item, $key)
 {
 if($key == 'admin_label' && $item == 'C02') {
   // find next key named number and update that value
} else if($key == 'admin_label' && $item == 'C03') {
   // find next key named number and update that value
} else if($key == 'admin_label' && $item == 'C04') {
   // find next key named number and update that value
}
 }

 array_walk_recursive($json, 'findarray');
```

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the structure of your JSON You can try something like this:

```
    <?php
    function myfunction($json, $field, $value)
    {
     foreach($json as $key11  => $pro1){
        foreach($pro1['columns'] as $key1  => $pro){
        foreach($pro as $k => $products){
       foreach($products as $key => $product)
       {
          if ( $product['settings'][$field] === $value ){
              $json[$key11]['columns'][$key1][$k][$key]['settings']['counter_title']="FOUND IT";
            break;
                  }
       }
        }
        }
}
       return $json;
    }


     $json[15]['columns'][1]['addons'][2]['settings']['number'] ='val1';
     $json[15]['columns'][2]['addons'][2]['settings']['number'] = 'val2';
     $json[15]['columns'][3]['addons'][2]['settings']['number'] = 'val3';
     $json[15]['columns'][4]['addons'][2]['settings']['number'] = 'val4';

        $x= myfunction($json, 'number', 'val3');


     print_r($x);
```

[DEMO HERE](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/845a4e526e425d4a4f135a9a343d0b5c053cb750)

Comment: Hey Thanks!. But if the parent key change..., lets say it change to 16 instead of 15, does it not break the function? it will be updating something else.

Comment: @Aramil hey i have updated the answer. but if every thing is dynamic then you need to loop through all of them to find the value matching in that case it may update more than one key value pair if found same.

Comment: Thanks Suchit! It work perfectly,  i modify it by adding a extra variable to the function myfunction($json, $field, $value, $val), and modifying $json[$key11]['columns'][$key1][$k][$key]['settings']['counter_title']="FOUND IT"; by $json[$key11]['columns'][$key1][$k][$key]['settings']['number']=$val;, that way i can use the function to check by the ID key, lets say $x= myfunction($json, 'admin_label', 'C02',$val); and it will update the number key with the values passed, brilliant bro thanks!.